How do I handle a rotation texture of Vertex Animation Textures (VAT)?
I have vertex animation textures exported by Labs Vertex Animation Textures ROP in Houdini.
Now I want to use it in my own game made with Bevy (a game engine written in Rust), not Unity or UE.
I made a custom material on Rust side which sends these data to WGSL shader:
@group(2) @binding(0) var<uniform> elapsed: f32; // elapsed time [s]
@group(2) @binding(1) var<uniform> fps: f32; // frames per sec
@group(2) @binding(2) var<uniform> total_frames: u32; // total frames in animation
@group(2) @binding(3) var<uniform> total_points: u32; // total points in mesh
@group(2) @binding(4) var<uniform> texture_width: u32; // width of VAT
@group(2) @binding(5) var position_texture: texture_2d<f32>;
@group(2) @binding(6) var rotation_texture: texture_2d<f32>;

Then, I wrote the vertex shader:
fn rotate_v(q: vec4<f32>, v: vec3<f32>) -> vec3<f32> {
    let qv = cross(q.xyz, v);
    return normalize(v + 2. * cross(q.xyz, qv + q.w * v));
}

@vertex
fn vertex(in: Vertex) -> VertexOutput {
    var out: VertexOutput;
    let frame = u32(round(elapsed * fps)) % total_frames + 1;
    let ptnum = u32(round(in.color.r * 256.)); // I used @Cd.r to transfer point number to vertex shader.
    let x = ptnum % texture_width;
    let stride = (total_points - 1) / texture_width + 1;
    let y = (frame - 1) * stride + ptnum / texture_width;

    let p = textureLoad(position_texture, vec2<u32>(x, y), 0); // relative position (x, y, z, 1)
    let enc_q = textureLoad(rotation_texture, vec2<u32>(x, y), 0); // encoded quarternion (x, y, z, w)
    let q = normalize(2. * enc_q - 1.);

    // set position
    let vat_position = vec4<f32>(in.position + p.xyz, 1.);
    out.local_position = vec4<f32>(in.position, 1);
    out.world_position = meshf::mesh_position_local_to_world(meshf::get_model_matrix(in.instance_index), vat_position);
    out.clip_position = meshf::mesh_position_local_to_clip(meshf::get_model_matrix(in.instance_index), vat_position);

    // set normal
    let vat_normal = rotate_v(q, in.normal);
    out.local_normal = in.normal;
    out.world_normal = meshf::mesh_normal_local_to_world(vat_normal, in.instance_index);

    return out;
}

Additionally I made the fragment shader to confirm if it works:
@fragment
fn fragment(in: VertexOutput) -> @location(0) vec4<f32> {
    let r = (2. + round(dot(in.local_normal, vec3<f32>(1., 0., 0.)))) / 3.;
    let g = (2. + round(dot(in.local_normal, vec3<f32>(0., 1., 0.)))) / 3.;
    let b = (2. + round(dot(in.local_normal, vec3<f32>(0., 0., 1.)))) / 3.;

    let l = (1. + dot(in.world_normal, vec3<f32>(0., 1., 0))) / 2.;

    let col = vec3<f32>(r, g, b) * l;

    return vec4<f32>(col, 1);
}

Fortunately, it worked with respect to position. Normal, however, did not. It was supposed to darken the bottom of a rotating cube, but actually left a dirty pattern all around.
I want to know how to handle the rotation texture and fix the shader.
I'm not so familiar with quarternions and VAT, so there may be some misunderstanding.
Can you help me with this?

You are loading the texture in the vertex shader?  I've never seen that before.  If you just want the texture size then it's more normal to send that in using a uniform or something.

Self Answer:
Here are a few points to note about the problem:

The quaternions in the rotation textures are not limited to the [0, 1] range. Therefore, the line let q = normalize(2. * enc_q - 1.); is unnecessary.

This quaternion transforms the "Y-axis" (0, 1, 0) into animated normals. Thus, it should be corrected to let vat_normal = rotate_v(q, vec3<f32>(0., 1., 0.));.


By addressing these points, I was able to achieve proper animated normals.
